# How to SaveInstanceState on dialog class?

Tags: android, dialog

In my application i have a 45 "editText" . now, when the user rotate the device the dialog closed and all the data are gone. so i created  a "public static boolean isShow = false" variable in the Dialogclass and it true is the dialog are "show"  and on my MainActivity i saved to the bundle and it's work my dialog not closed beacuse i create a new dialog when "isShow" = false. but all the data cleared . My question is do i need to save all of the 45 editText one by one? if i need , there is a way to cancel the rotation only for this dialog?

```
public  class DialogSetting extends Dialog {

public static boolean isShow = false;

    public DialogSetting(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_setting);
        this.context = context;

        this.show();
        isShow = true;


        this.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                isShow = false;
            }
        });

    }


public void close(View v){
 isShow = false;
this.dismiss();
}
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putBoolean("dialogSetting", DialogSetting.isShow);
}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


    DialogSetting.isShow = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("dialogSetting");

    if(DialogSetting.isShow){
    new DialogSetting(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: You should inherit your dialog from `DialogFragment`. If you're doing this the `FragmentManager` will take care of recreating the Fragment after rotating the device.

So here's how your Dialog class should look like:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static MyDialog newInstance(){
        MyDialog f = new MyDialog();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_setting, container, false);
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Everything else that needs to be done to setup the dialog (findViewById, Listener etc.)

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here's how you need to call the Dialog (slightly more complex):

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
if (prev != null) {
   ft.remove(prev);
}
ft.addToBackStack(null);
MyDialog dialogFragment = MyDialog.newInstance();
dialogFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
```

To prevent any loss of data because of the rotation, you need to save the data in a bundle inside the dialog (basically the same as you did in your `Activity`). 
Here's a basic example of saving the entered text of an `EditText`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        text = savedInstanceState.getString("et_text");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("et_text", mEditText.getText().toString());
}
```

You can read more about `DialogFragments` in the [docs(click)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Comment: i can't understand what the diffrent and what better, and in my question i want to skip the part of saving instance for the editText beacuse i have alot of edittext

Comment: Ok here's the good thing. The `FragmentManager` keeps the input of the `EditText` as well. So you don't have to save the input manually. My bad ;)